# How to use bash/sed to extract XML attribute value

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

I have the following grep command piped into sed to find an element name attribute and store the sed result into a name variable.

```
 name=$(grep -E "<element.*name=.*/>" "$F" | sed -e "s/.*<element.*name=\(.*\)\/>.*?/\1/")
```

Sample Data -

```
<element name="Barium"/>
```

Desired Output -

```
Barium
```

Actual Output -

```
<element name="Barium"/>
```

I'm a little confused on how to get the sed command to get rid of the excess.

(I know xmllint would make this easy, but can't use it for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sed for this:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<element name=")[^"]+' <file>
```

Or

```
grep -Po '<element name="\K[^"]+' <file>
```